# Is there a WordStar or even WordPerfect for Android and iOS?

Tags: android, dos

I honestly wanted a 1980s retro word processor that looks very similar to WordStar and WordPerfect and whatever word processor in that decade for my Android tablet.  I tried looking for them on app stores to no avail. From what I seen on the Internet, I really like the WordStar's and WordPerfect's layout. Looks very comfortable and probably good for my eyes haha (I tend to have eye strains occasionally, especially when I'm staring at the white page for a while so black kinda helps and it kinda made my eyestrain go away). Are there any of those retro word processors for Android and iOS?

Comment: I don't think this is a retrocomputing question. Why would their manufacturers bother to republish old programs under modern OSes? Also what prevents you from running them in an emulator?

Comment: I don't know about Android but I would hate having to map unshifted, shifted, control, and alt keystrokes for F1-F12 on a tablet keyboard.

Comment: @Justme , I don't have a laptop or a PC (just a Android tablet and an iPhone) and I thought most WordStar emulators, even clones, can only run on a computer.

Comment: Your tablet is hundreds of times faster than an old DOS computer and can emulate a DOS computer running any DOS program.

Comment: I hated WordStar and WordPerfect, but I was a big fan of the early DOS Microsoft Word, and it runs just fine on aDOSBox, a port of DOSBox to Android.

Comment: @doneal24, Some of us use an actual, physical, bluetooth-connected keyboard with our Android tablet when we want to enter more than a trivial amount of text. Mine has Alt keys and F1 through F12 keys. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0B8M9NM56/

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found any native Android apps either. But you may try an online [WordStar emulator](https://www.pcjs.org/software/pcx86/app/other/wordstar) at [PCjs](https://www.pcjs.org), for example [WordStar 3.30](https://www.pcjs.org/software/pcx86/app/other/wordstar/3.30). The Android virtual keyboard doesn't work though, so you need to tap the `Keys` button to bring up the emulator's own virtual keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is running either (even M$Works 2.0) on a [DOSBoX](https://dosbox.com) box on my Android tablet: it does the job, save printing, which I bypass by printing to a PostScript file and processing as PDF.

Comment: Already downloaded two DosBox apps (aDosBox via APK and IDosBox via Google Play Store) on my Android tablet and not even a YouTube video nor a Google search helped me at all. It's my first time using a DOS emulator to be honest but even then I tried to type out commands I seen on tutorial videos and that didn't work. :/

Comment: I'd love to see what youtube video you tried, to give an opinion...

Comment: I tried those videos: 
 https://youtu.be/hLzmNwhFyBU, https://youtu.be/4Wd8K2n5ayk, and https://youtu.be/1bKNts8liWI

Comment: you need to install your copy of wordstar on the dosbox directory, to run it from within the emulator. try this tutorial video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXzLfBEChrA on "mounting dosbox directory on android".

Comment: @jarnosz, took me hours to understand it and figure it out, partly because I downloaded the wrong WordStar files and I have bit of hard time following instructions but I finally got both of them to run Wordstar :) You said you can save them to a Postscript file and process them as PDF. How exactly did that work on a tablet, may I ask?

Comment: iirc, the latest versions of msword, msworks and wordperfect have postscript drivers, while wordstar had only support for pcl (hewlett-packard's printer command language): in any event, if you print to a file, and then load the printer output with an appropriate PS/PCL android app, you may send the output to a printer.

Comment: you know any good app for this?